# how to test out parameter from Oracle in C#

Tags: c#, oracle, unit-testing, rhino-mocks, out

I have written a function that retrieve some data from database (using a stored procedure, Oracle database).

The stored procedure has 4 parameter and one of them is am out parameter. Here is my code for this:

```
string commandName = "someStoredProc";
List<IDataParameter> parameters = new List<IDataParameter>() { new SqlParameter("@param1", param1), new SqlParameter("@param2", param2), new SqlParameter("@param3", param3) };

SqlParameter calcId = new SqlParameter("@param4", SqlDbType.BigInt);
calcId.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

parameters.Add(calcId);

Dictionary<long, ITrade> trades = _genericDataReader.ExecuteSqlQuery(parameters, CommandTypeEnum.Command, commandName);

long CalculationID =  (long)calcId.Value;
```

This code is working fine.

Now I am writing unit test cases for this. I am able to mock the database result whatever I want but not this fourth out Parameter:

> test failed when it try to convert calcId.Value to long as it is null.

How can I mock this out parameter value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is actually necessary here is writting an implementation of `ExecuteSqlQuery` for testing purpose, which has an access to the arguments and can do the job.
Rhino Mock provides a few ways to add a custom behavior to mocks/stubs. One of possible ways is to write [The Do() handler](http://www.ayende.com/wiki/Rhino+Mocks+The+Do%28%29+Handler.ashx).

Here is a short example:

```
_genericDataReader
    .Stub(gdr => gdr.ExecuteSqlQuery(Arg<List<IDataParameter>>.Is.Anything, Arg<CommandTypeEnum>.Is.Anything, Arg<string>.Is.Anything))
    .Do((Func<List<IDataParameter>, CommandTypeEnum, string, IDictionary<long, ITrade>>)((param, cmd, cmdName) =>
    {
        param[3].Value = 12L;
        return null; // or return whatever is required dataset here
    }));
```